# Save failed with the following error: Unknown column 'created' in 'field list'

Tags: custom-component, jtable

As I develop the back end manage record functionality of a component, I am getting "Save failed with the following error: Unknown column 'created' in 'field list'"

I built the helloworld component according to the Joomla docs tutorial: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Introduction

I am trying to extend the back-end from simply displaying the list of items ( https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Basic_backend ) to modify (i.e., manage) each record. For this, I copied the back-end's com_banners banner view and the related files (controller, model, table, etc.), and adjusted the files to reflect the structure of my component's single record.

My component's table only has 3 columns, id, greeting, and state.

The manage record view for my component is displaying the record correctly, but when I modify the greeting and try to save it, I get the error

> "Save failed with the following error: Unknown column 'created' in
>   'field list'"

Like I said, the table of my component only has 3 columns, id, greeting, and state. The error implies the query included the additional column 'created'. Why is this additional column added to the query?

#### UPDATE:

@Sharky suggested to delete `$this->created = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();` from the Table class of the component. I did, and then I got the error

> "Save failed with the following error: Unknown column 'modified' in
>   'field list'"

Right now, the Table class for my component looks like:

```
class HelloWorldTableHelloWorld extends JTable
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param   JDatabaseDriver  $db  Database connector object
     *
     * @since   1.5
     */
    public function __construct(&$db)
    {

        parent::__construct('#__helloworld', 'id', $db);

        JTableObserverContenthistory::createObserver($this, array('typeAlias' => 'com_helloworld.helloworld'));

        $this->setColumnAlias('published', 'state');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have missed something when adapting the files to your table structure. Run a search for `created` through the files. It could be this line in `/administrator/com_banners/tables/banner.php`:

```
$this->created = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();
```

Also, look at the class of your component's model.

Based on your update, and given the advice I gave you (i.e., review your component for Banner's specific code), from class HelloWorldModelHelloWorld, you would delete the lines from method prepareTable:

```
$table->modified    = $date->toSql();
$table->modified_by = $user->id;
$table->version++;
```

Comment: Deleting $this->created = JFactory::getDate()->toSql(); from the HelloWorldTableHelloWorld did not work.  I am now getting the error "Save failed with the following error: Unknown column 'modified' in 'field list'"